# How to get a "slice" of an LLVM array?

Tags: llvm

The following line works successfully in LLVM:

```
%r1 = extractvalue [6 x i1] [i1 0, i1 1, i1 0, i1 1, i1 0, i1 0], 1
```

But the following line leads to an error in `llc` (notice the second index at the end of the line):

```
%r1 = extractvalue [6 x i1] [i1 0, i1 1, i1 0, i1 1, i1 0, i1 0], 1, 2
```

Error message: `error: invalid indices for extractvalue`.

Is it possible to get a slice of an array in LLVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `extractvalue` followed by one or more `insertvalue` instructions.

This will not look nice, but it'll result in the same native code output as a hypothetical nicer solution.

The syntax with multiple indices is there to support nested structs/arrays. If you want to extract an int from an array of array of ints, you need two indices.

Comment: Would this be an `extractvalue` followed by `insertvalue` for every element in the slice? The LLVM language reference manual suggests that multiple indices can be used; is that incorrect? https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#extractvalue-instruction

Comment: For every element, yes. Multiple indices are used for nested structs/arrays, not for slices. If you have an array of array of int, you need two indices to extract an int.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for clarifying the use of multiple indices! Can you add that to your answer as well, and then I'll mark as accepted?

And thanks for letting me know that `extractvalue` by `insertvalue` can lead to the same native code output, I would have assumed that was a terribly inefficient approach!